# How to pass a defined and an undefined number of arguments to a function the same time in php?

Tags: php, function

I hope the title isn't too confusing. I'll try to explain exactly what i mean.

I'm trying to create a function to get database values from a prepared statement. There may be times I just have to pass one argument, like when I'm just searching for a specific string. For example:

```
$query = "SELECT `nr1`, `nr2`, `nr3` FROM test WHERE test1 = ?"
```

I would then use the following to bind parameters:

```
$query->bind_param('s', $parameter);
```

My problem is: how can i fill bind_param with more than just 1 parameter after the 's' part? Let's say I have this query:

```
$query = "SELECT `nr1`, `nr2`, `nr3` FROM test WHERE test1 = ? AND test2 = ?"
```

I would need to do this to bind parameters:

```
$query->bind_param('ss', $parameter1, $parameter2);
```

As you see the first parameter of bind_param is always a string containing the type(s) of the expected result. Then there's an undefined number of variables I have to pass with a function. For the first example I would use

```
function get_the_result($query,$type,$param) {
    [...]
    $stmt=$query;
    [...]
    $stmt->bind_param($type, $param);
    [...]        
}
```

Now how can this be done for multiple parameters where I use $param? I could imagine there's a way doing this with $param as an array, but I think bind_param expects a normal variable.

Is there a way to do this? also I'm new here, so if there's a way to improve my question or if there's something you need to know that I forgot to tell you, just tell me :)

Thank you in advance

Comment: A hint: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Comment: you could either use the new-ish `...` vararg syntax or simply pass an array of values to your function.

Comment: Thank you. As far as I understand, this would allow me to pass multiple parameters to the function after the 'ss' part. But as far as I know bind_param() only accepts normal variables and no arrays. I need to pass the list of variables to it like bind_param('ss', $param1, $param2) and I have no idea how I'm able to do that. There might be 3 parameters to pass if theres three "?" in the statement or just 1 parameter if there's one "?".

Comment: @SamyX Take a look again at the example in the manual :) It's what you need

Comment: Thank you very much. Figured it out thanks to you :)
(I guess) I can't give a +1 to you, since I'm new here. So I hope someone else does it for me.